# Is using "seeing" in this case wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction, indian-english

Question:

> The couple who saw her off were probably her parents. (Make it Simple)

My answer:

> The couple seeing her off were probably her parents.

My teacher said that my answer is wrong, and the proper answer should be:

> The couple, probably her parents, saw her off.

When I asked why my answer is wrong, he said that the word "seeing" isn't used in these cases and whenever there is a single subject, to make it a simple sentence "ing" is used in the start of the sentence.

I understand that I have used "seeing" as the 3rd word in the sentence, rather than at first; but I don't understand why is that an issue?

Comment: The couple drinking beer were my parents. The couple singing loudly were Scottish. The couple eating cheese were arrested. All fine. Your teacher is mistaken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question\ Difference between "It was someone doing sth or who did sth"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83800/question-difference-between-it-was-someone-doing-sth-or-who-did-sth)

Comment: I don't know whether the sentence you wrote is a simple sentence. But simple or not, that sentence is correct. I think there is no wrong use of "seeing" in your sentence. But if the sentence you wrote is not a simple sentence, then your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is your teacher's evaluation of your sentence at fault (there is nothing wrong with your sentence) but your teacher's paraphrase has a different meaning.

The basic proposition of the original sentence is *The couple were probably her parents*. Your version preserves that.

The basic proposition of your teacher's sentence is *The couple saw her off*.

While these both refer to the same situation, they are answers to entirely different questions.

Your teacher's explanation sounds as if they are thinking of the *gerund phrase* "Seeing her off", which can be the subject of a verb (eg *Seeing her off was all I wanted to do.*) But that is a different construction from your *participial phrase* functioning adjectivally, and synonymous with the relative clause *who saw her off* in the original.